# ways of removing cubes

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

i got

size 4 = 8; 
size 3 = 8+6*2*2 = 32
size 2 = 8+24*2*2 = 104
size 1 = 8+36*2 = 80

but would like to see if there's better ideas. Thanks!

Comment: What are the 32 ways you have found for size 3?

Comment: 8 for rm 2; 6*2*2 for rm 1 and 1

Comment: Shouldn’t there be 125 ways for size 1 as there are 125 cubes of size 1?

Comment: I have no idea what "8 for rm 2; 6*2*2 for rm 1 and 1" means. Could you spell it out a bit more for me, please?

Comment: Hint: This is the 3-dimensional version a famous 2-d problem: How many squares are there on a 5x5 chessboard? (Not just the 1x1 squares, but also the 2x2, 3x3, etc.) If you can work out the formula in 2-d, you'll have a good guess for the answer in 3-d. If you can't work out the formula in 2-d, try to answer the 1-d version "how many line segments are on a line segment that is divided into 5 line segments".

Answer (score 1):

More generally, in order to cut a $r\times r \times r$ cube  from a given $n\times n \times n$ cube with $1\leq r\leq n$, we select $3$ pairs of planes which are parallel to each pair of opposite faces of the cube such that their distance is $r$. For each pair the number of ways is $(n+1-r)$. Therefore we find that the total number of ways is $(n+1-r)^3$

Answer (score 0):

For edges with $k$ units, the cube can be on $5-k+1$ different place for $x$-axis. Likewise, $5-k+1$ different place for $y$ and $z$-axis. Thus the result will be $(5-k+1)^3$